# How to echo and retrive multiple rows with php

Tags: javascript, php

First off all hello to you all. The problem is I am making an ajax call from javascript to php file. And in that php file there is a prepared statement which returns 15 rows. I need to json_encode() these rows and send back to the javascript file so that I can use all of these information in each row which are info about users' profile. What's wrong with my code? I call fetch_assoc() constantly until all of the rows are processed yet when I display it on the console it only shows one row.

This is get_info.php:

```
 // Get the profile info
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT teachers.fname, teachers.lname, profile.img_url, profile.gender, profile.introduction, profile.city, profile.preference, profile.keyword FROM profile INNER JOIN teachers ON profile.user_id = teachers.id WHERE profile.keyword=? ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 15");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $keyword);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result(); // get the mysqli result
    $resultArray = [];
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
    {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {   
            $resultArray = $row;    
        }
        $result = json_encode($resultArray);
        echo $result;
    }
```

And this is the javascript file where the ajax request is:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
  $.getJSON("get_info.php", function(result)
  {
    console.log(result);
  }
)})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep overwriting `$resultArray` every time you loop, so you'll only ever see the last row returned by the query.

You need to make assign `$row` to a new element of `$resultArray` each time you loop - then adds rows to the array, instead of overwriting the variable with a single row.

It's very simple to do that:

```
$resultArray[] = $row;
```

You may also want to read https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying to refresh your memory of this key bit of PHP syntax.

Comment: I was going out of my mind. Thanks for the answer. I do appreciate it and you are right I need to check php syntax as I have not been using it for a long time.